# Is Cassandra meant to be used as one big table?

Tags: database, postgresql, cassandra

Most articles on Cassandra focus on the hardware benefits

1. Distributes across multiple nodes
2. Performance scales linearly
3. Increased redundancy

However, at our office, we are considering making a move from PostgreSQL to Cassandra for the simple reason that in Cassandra one can toss everything in a table like it's the wild west.

Therefore, the general approach at our office is currently like so

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person (
   id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   fname VARCHAR(256)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Job (
   id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   employeeId  INT REFERENCES (Person)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Car (
   id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   ownerId INT REFERENCES (Person),
   year INT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Insurance (
   id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   carId   INT REFERENCES (Car)
);
```

But we are considering moving towards Cassandra to carry out something like the following

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lazy (
   id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   fname VARCHAR(256),
   employeeId  INT REFERENCES (Person)
   ownerId INT REFERENCES (Person),
   year INT
   carId   INT REFERENCES (Car)
);
```

Every programming fibre in my body is telling me that this is wrong, but converting our front end from an object oriented hierarchical structure to Postgres' relational model is nightmare as we have a great deal of nested foreign keys.

Is this how Cassandra is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on your access patterns for your data.

Considering your example (removing the unsupported features):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lazy (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   fname VARCHAR(256),
   employeeId INT,
   ownerId INT,
   year INT,
   carId INT,
);
```

You will **only** be able to search by id. You provide the id and you can get any of the fields fname, employeeId, ownerId, year, carId. You can't query using any of the other id fields.

You could search on these by adding them as clustering columns as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lazy (
   id INT,
   fname VARCHAR(256),
   employeeId INT,
   ownerId INT,
   year INT,
   carId INT,
   PRIMARY KEY((id), employeeId, ownerId, carId)
);
```

Now you will be able to search on the fields *employeeId*, *ownerId* and *carId*... but only if you also provide the partition key *id*. Also the ordering in the primary key definition matters. To search by one of the clustering columns, you must provide all the preceding columns. i.e. if you want to search by carId, you must also provide employeeId and ownerId (as well as id).

I doubt this is what you actually want. I suggested doing some research into data modelling with Cassandra and see what Cassandra is optimised for. You will likely end up wanting several tables such as:

```
Persons_by_id
Persons_by_car
Persons_by_job
Cars_by_job
```

etc

Comment: The more I think of your multiple tables suggestions, the more it starts to sound like `views` to me

Comment: It is probably very similar because often you will construct a view in an RDBMS of data that you want to be displayed together, and this is often what you would want your application to display/use as well. The goal in Cassandra is to have a data model so that you only need to look at one table and do one sweep of the data to get everything you need then return to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra Data model will be according to query . Mean what output you want from cassandra . don't think like relational model . cassandra database is no-sql so  you can write one type of data into more table . Because cassandra don't have joins thats why you have to put all data in one table according to your query .

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Unfortunately, this is not very clear. Could you please edit it.